# Passing data to other tab in IE11 when using local files (file://)

Tags: cookies, local-storage, internet-explorer-11, postmessage, local-files

I have an application where one or more tabs pass "display requests" (i.e. to display data relevant to some data query) to a dedicated tab. That tab is launched using a known window name and the initial HTML written to it using `win.document.write` calls. The request data is passed to it using `localStorage` and that dedicated tab listens for associated `storage` events.

This all works fine, even when running using a local-file protocol (`file:///`), ... except in IE11. I have a committent to support IE11 (I don't care about older versions), and the local-file scenario is used by my customers before deploying their working configurations to their websites.

My question is whether there's a reliable alternative mechanism that I can fall back to with IE11 when using `file:///`.

My library code has provision for a fall-back mechanism if `localStorage` is undefined, but it seems that everything fails. I have tried cookies (obviously using a different type of "nudge" than `storage` events) and `postMessage`, but all have fallen foul of poorly-documented IE limitations.

My data requests are not of a fixed size but I could happily justify a limitation to about 1K if necessary. Any suggestions for how to pass such textual data would be very welcome.

[UPDATE: I have tried directly manipulating data in the other window object, but it really needs a user-defined (or innocuous) event for synchronisation. Most people would recommend `storage` or `message` events for that but then I'd be back with the same problem. I have also tried using URL fragments, which at least has its own `hashchanged` event, but there are size limits that depend on the user's browser and are not documented in most cases.]

Comment: [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#description) data is specific to the protocol of the document. As far as I know, IE don't support localStorage object if there is no server. So I think your needs cannot be implemented.

Comment: I know it's not supported in IE, but it works everywhere else, including with file://. It does not require a server . That's why I'm looking for an alternative "fallback" mechanism

Comment: The answer here from 13 June 2017 is really helpful in making use of URL fragments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16247162/max-size-of-location-hash-in-browser